# how to customize data series label/tooltips with flot graph

Tags: label, flot, tooltip

By default the data series info/tooltips in flot graph looks like "legend_title of 2.00 = 1234567890.00" Is it possible to remove the .00 or customize to other format? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Flot doesn't really provide a "built in" tooltip but rather a way to create your own tooltips.  From your question, I gather you are following the example [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html).  If you want to customize what the tooltip says just call the showTooltip function with a different "contents".

For instance, To drop the zero's off the numbers call it as:

```
showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
   item.series.label + " of " + x.toFixed(0) + " = " + y.toFixed(0));
```

But you can further format it any way you want!